# How to get the name of the calling program in an asynchronous background task?

Tags: abap, saprfc

How to get the name of the calling program from within an asynchronous remote function call (aRFC) ?

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEREPLICA' STARTING NEW TASK lv_taskname
  DESTINATION IN GROUP DEFAULT
```

The called BAPI triggers a user exit that I need to disable for this particular calling program. However, the local part of the stack is lost after the RFC and the name of the calling program on the local system is unknown.

The closest solution I could think of was disabling the user exit when the calling program is SAPMSSY1 (RFC calls), but that it not as accurate.

Comment: Maybe the parameter `CALLER_PROGRAM` of the function module `RFC_GET_ATTRIBUTES`. I'm not sure it works in all kinds of RFC calls.

Comment: It works, thanks Sandra! Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: is it possible at all? I'm not sure. Any approach (including Sandra's) will not work if the call came from external middleware or by any other means

Comment: @Suncatcher But that's not relevant in a case like this where you use aRFC solely for parallelization within the same system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the parameter `CALLER_PROGRAM` of the function module `RFC_GET_ATTRIBUTES`. I'm not sure it works in all kinds of RFC calls.